# Controls for buiding 3d curves & plots in WinForms or WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, plot, curves

For my course project I need some control for building three-dimensional curves & plots graphs. I've searhed the web, but i was not able to find the needed library. 
The basic requironment to the control is the ability to build curve/plot from set of 3d points.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify free versus paid controls but I didn't find any free ones that seemed to do what you want.  However, there are a couple paid ones out there is that will do what you want.  These include:

Telerik's 3D line chart:  http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/chart.aspx#support-for-16-3d-chart-types

Graph Now's Visual Data:  http://www.graphnow.com/visual-data.html

The Visual Data product is only $150 but I've never used it.  The Telerik controls are more expensive but they come in a bundle and I can attest that they are well worth the cost.

Comment: Thanks. Graph Now's Visual Data seems to be what I was looking for.